# Why doesn't roxygen write package info to DESCRIPTION?

Tags: r, roxygen

I followed the [Vignette](http://roxygen.org/roxygen.pdf) and found that information such as License, Author, etc. in pseudoprime-package.Rd is not written to DESCRIPTION?  Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you write the DESCRIPTION, not roxygen.  (Despite the confusing example in the documentation)

Comment: Wouldn't that be "you write part of the DESCRIPTION"? Because someone keeps filling in my `collate` fields...

Comment: Roxygen fills in the parts that can be filled in automatically.

Comment: could you explain further?  Which parts can be filled automatically?  For example, it seems like "author" could be filled automatically but in fact roxygen doesn't copy author information over to DESCRIPTION

Comment: As Sharpie said, collate gets filled in automatically. Nothing else does

Comment: @hadley: what would be the best documentation on Roxygen2?

Comment: The help files should list everything. File a bug if they don't or you can't understand them.